# How to get list of flows in app using mule expression language or java

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I have to print the list of flows in the present application. Please help me out.

Comment: For each flow, you can take the flow name by using this MEL  `#[flow.name]`

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your Java class implements *Callable*, and use the following script `eventContext.getMuleContext().getRegistry().lookupFlowConstructs()` to get the list of Flow.